# Custom Guzzle serialization

Tags: php, json, symfony, guzzle

I would like to have a custom serialization in Guzzle.

I'm setting a `POST` `application/json` request, but my object is serialized with its name (professionalSession) at the beginning, i.e.:

```
{
 professionalSession :
  {
    param1 : "asdf",
    param2 : "jkl;",
    ...
   }
}
```

That is inconsistent with the REST API I'm trying to call. (className is hidden as one of the parameters).

This is my definition in `serviceDescription.json`:

```
"PostAuthentication": {
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "/xxx-person-service/session",
        "summary": "Posts the session object",
        "type": "json",
        "responseClass": "XXX\\WebServicesClientBundle\\Entity\\ProfessionalSession",
        "parameters":{
            "session": {
                "location": "json",
                "required": true
            },
            "session-identifier": {
                "location": "header",
                "required": true,
                "sentAs": "HTTP_X_SESSION_KEY"
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to use `serviceDescription.json` and only override its 1 parameter (by produce json myself).

I tried changing the location of param to `body` (as it was said in SO somewhere), but Content-Type is not being properly set to `application/json`.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reply as there are no responses yet and I've overcame this problem.
Changing the location of param to `body` was good approach as it removes that top level JSON element. (This was signaled as a problem, but still - this is how Guzzle behaves.)

To change request to `application/json` you can use following description in `serviceDescription.json`:

```
   "PostAuthentication": {
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "uri": "/xxx-person-service/session",
        "summary": "Posts the session object",
        "responseClass": "XXX\\WebServicesClientBundle\\Entity\\ProfessionalSession",
        "parameters":{
            "session": {
                 "location": "body",
                 "required": true
            },
            "session-identifier": {
                "location": "header",
                "required": true,
                "sentAs": "HTTP_X_SESSION_KEY"
            },
            //THIS is what you need:
            "content-type": {
                "location": "header",
                "static": true,
                "required" : true,
                "default" : "application/json",
                "sentAs" : "Content-Type"
            }
        }
    },
```